# "No select item" on JavaFX combobox?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

What is the correct way to put an item which value is null, inside a ComboBox?
I tried using `myComboBox.getItems().add(null);`, and it works, but whenever the user selects this value on the combo box, an exception is thrown on the console:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:136)
```

So i think maybe this is not the correct way of doing that. Any clues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience, this is a problem introduced in Java 8u20. In Java 8u05 and 8u11, as well as JavaFX 2.x, you could add `null` to the list of items, and selecting this item behaved as expected. In Java 8u20 you will get a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` whenever selecting the `null` value.

Benjamin Gale: you will have to use Java 8u20, select an item in the ComboBox, and then select the `null` value to see the issue.

At the current time, the best option seems to be to create a special `null`-object and label it appropriately, as already mentioned.

Alternatively, if you can get by with using a ChoiceBox instead, I think you will find that it works the way you want.

Comment: Strange, my system is reporting that I have Java 8 update 20 and the code I posted works fine.

Comment: Yes, that is weird. I'm not sure what it means that your _system is reporting_ that you have Java 8 update 20. Are you sure you are actually using it to run the code? If you insert `System.out.println("Java version is: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));` into the code and run it, does it print "Java version is: 1.8.0_20"?

Comment: @BenjaminGale confirmed the IOOB in 8u20 (but then, having a null doesn't make overly much sense anyway, as we agree)

Comment: Can confirm, not possible on java 8_31 too. Adding null value results in an index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be something with your code that you are not showing us as the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) below works fine and doesn't throw any exceptions.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NullComboBoxApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Option 1",
                "Option 2",
                "Option 3"
        ));

        cb.getItems().add(null);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(cb);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Null ComboBox Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Although this actually works, quite why you'd want your users to be able to select `null` is beyond me...is this actually the behaviour you want? I suspect you really want to be able to clear the current selection, something like:

```
cb.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

Comment: I think that SO wants to give user the ability to select an empty value in combobox. If this is the case, then I recommend to create special NULL object (Object that will represent empty state of combobox) and add it to items list. For example, in your case it may be just an empty string. To avoid situations where you still can get null as selected value, you can force selection at controller initialization by calling `cb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst()`

Comment: That still does not make sense to me. You would still have an 'empty' value displayed in your `ComboBox`. What does it mean to select an empty value? If the user is to interact with it then it should be appropriately labeled e.g. `<<Clear Selection>>`.

Comment: There's no such thing as an empty value in Combobox (at least right now). There's state of Combobox, when nothing is yet selected. But when user selects something for a first time, user cannot undo his selection to previous state. To give this ability, you should create an empty value yourself and add it to the list of possible values. And you can name it as you want: empty, no data, etc.

Comment: Which is what I have already said. From my original post: "I suspect you really want to be able to clear the current selection" and from my comment above: "If the user is to interact with it then it should be appropriately labeled e.g. `<<Clear Selection>>`" My code example shows that you can have an 'empty' value in a combo box even if it makes no sense, which is the point I am making! :-)

Comment: never-ever add real nulls: a) technically, selecting a null results in clearing the selection (open issue, because that's unspecified - https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38494), so if a null is a contained item the system will get confused b) 100% ACK with Benjamin: doesn't make sense for the user to _select_ a "null" c) what can make sense is to _clear_ the selection: the keyboard gesture to achieve that is ctrl-space (doesn't work always, though, you might need a custom key binding) d) consider using a text prompt to improve the user experience if nothing selected

Comment: I've tested your example and with JDK1.8.0.74 this throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works again in newer versions. As for me with JavaFX 15.0.1.

EDIT for @Kirby:
I'm using Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0) which uses Eclipse OpenJDK 15.0.1. In my Gradle Build I use the javafxplugin.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}
```

with the plugin configuration

```
javafx {
    version = '15.0.1'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
```

The object I am using in the ComboBox has implemented toString.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

My Combobox is filled like that:

```
ObservableList<MyExample> allMyExamplesList = loadMyExamples();
if (allMyExamplesList != null) {
    allMyExamplesList.add(0, null);
    myExampleComboBox.setItems(allMyExamplesList );
}
```

[image: ComboBox with null entry]

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate a bit on your answer. Perhaps if you could shine some light on what it was in JavaFX 15.0.1 that made it work? Or perhaps some example of it working?

Comment: Edited my post for you.

Comment: never-ever override toString for application reasons .. instead, use a custom cell (for comboBox a StringConverter is another option) to configure the visuals

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Back then it was my first JavaFX project and I'm already using custom cell renderers for all components ; )